# How to re-code a movie file with Xuggler

Tags: java, video-encoding, xuggle, xuggler

This must be a very stupid question, but how does one recode with Xuggler?
Simplified I have:

```
IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(sourceUrl);      
IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(url, reader);

MediaSegmenterWriter writerListener = new MediaSegmenterWriter();
writer.open();
while (reader.readPacket() == null)
   do {
     } 
while(false);
```

Now, I want to recode the file in the reader to another bitrate and resolution. How do I do that? On creating the writer I have tried to add IMediaStreams with a copy of the original coder with the necessary changes, but that does not work:

```
    int numStreams = reader.getContainer().getNumStreams();
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
        final IStream stream = reader.getContainer().getStream(i);
        final IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

        IStreamCoder newCoder = IStreamCoder.make(IStreamCoder.Direction.ENCODING, coder);
        if(newCoder == null ){
            continue;
        }
        writer.getContainer().addNewStream(i);

        int streams = writer.getContainer().getNumStreams();
        System.out.println("Current amount of streams in writer: " + streams);

        System.out.println("Coder: " + coder.toString());
        if (coderSetting != null && newCoder != null){
            if (newCoder.getCodecType().equals(ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)) {
                newCoder.setWidth(320);
                newCoder.setHeight(240);                   
            } 
            IStream outputStream = writer.getContainer().getStream(i);
            outputStream.setStreamCoder(newCoder);
            newCoder.open();
          }
    }
```

But this just gives the same result as leaving the code out (e.g. 1920x1080 from original)

Also tried to add a listener to the writer and replace the coder, but either got an error (coder already opened_ or no effect. (on onOpen, onAddStream, onOpenCoder))

I looked for tutorials, but non seem to do this simple operation.

Any help would be REALLY appreciated!!!

Comment: I am searching for the same thing, do you find a solution for that ?? If yes, it will be so helpful !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resize the content as well as recode you need to create a MediaToolAdapter like:

```
private static class MediaResizer extends MediaToolAdapter {
    private IVideoResampler videoResampler = null;
    private int mediaHeight;
    private int mediaWidth;

    public MediaResizer (int aHight, int aWidth) {
        mediaWidth = aWidth;
        mediaHeight = aHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
        // In case of audio only, do not re-size as it is not needed
        if(job.role == MediaRole.MediaRoleEnum.LS_AUDIO) super.onVideoPicture(event);

        IVideoPicture pic = event.getPicture();

        if (videoResampler == null) {
            videoResampler = IVideoResampler.make(job.getCoderSettings().width, job.getCoderSettings().height, pic.getPixelType(), pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), pic.getPixelType());
        }

        IVideoPicture out = IVideoPicture.make(pic.getPixelType(), mediaWidth, mediaHeight);
        videoResampler.resample(out, pic);

        IVideoPictureEvent asc = new VideoPictureEvent(event.getSource(), out, event.getStreamIndex());
        super.onVideoPicture(asc);

        out.delete();
    }

}
```

You add this as a listener to your reader, and then your writer to you resized. It should be something like:

```
 IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(sourceUrl);
 MediaResizer resizer = new MediaResizer(job);
 IMediaWriter currentWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(destinationDir, reader);

 reader.addListener(resizer);
 resizer.addListener(currentWriter);
```

Comment: can you kindly tell what is "job" and what about this Constructer

Comment: I cannot remember, as it is a long time ago, and moved to evoke ffmpeg directly

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Umar,
Maybe he means:

```
@Override
    public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
//        Logger.info("onAddStream(): now I am in VideoConverter.onVideoPicture().....");
        IVideoPicture pic = event.getPicture();
        if (videoResampler == null) {
            videoResampler = IVideoResampler.make(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT,
                    pic.getPixelType(), pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(),
                    pic.getPixelType());
        }

        IVideoPicture out = IVideoPicture.make(pic.getPixelType(), VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);

        videoResampler.resample(out, pic);
        IVideoPictureEvent asc = new VideoPictureEvent(event.getSource(), out, event.getStreamIndex());
        super.onVideoPicture(asc);
        out.delete();
    }
```